# Is there a formula to calculate the minimum height of an n-nary tree with L leaves?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to calculate the minimum height of an n-nary tree with L leaves. Is there such a formula?

Comment: How many nodes can you fit at most at each level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it:

$$ \text{minimum height}= \lceil \log_n L \rceil$$